# Linux Shell-Script code is not executing as it should

Tags: linux, shell, bubble-sort

#### Bubble Sort : (Original Code)

```
clear
echo "Enter size : "
read size
echo "Enter elements : "
for (( i=0; i<size; i++ ))
do
    echo "Element " $i " : "
    read arr[$i]
done
m=$(($n-1))
for (( i=0; i<m; i++ ))
do
    cond=$((size-$i-1))
    for (( j=0; j<cond; j++ ))
    do
        l=$(($j+1));
        if [ ${a[$j]} -gt ${a[$l]} ]
        then
            tmp=${a[$j]}
            a[$j]=${a[$l]}
            a[$l]=$tmp
        fi
    done
done
echo "Sorted Data : "
echo ${a[*]}
```

This code is executing, while it takes the input and stores them in the array.
The the next thing I see is, "Sorted Array" being printed.
and no elements are printed after that.

Tried, `sh -x sort.sh` and the interim code isn't being executed. 
I am quite new to shell script and cannot understand what's wrong.

#### Bubble Sort : (Corrected Code)

```
clear
echo "Enter size : "
read size
echo "Enter elements : "
for (( i=0; i<size; i++ ))
do
    echo "Element " $i " : "
    read arr[$i]
done
m=$(($size-1))
for (( i=0; i<m; i++ ))
do
    cond=$(($size-$i-1))
    for (( j=0; j<cond; j++ ))
    do
        l=$(($j+1));
        if [ ${arr[$j]} -gt ${arr[$l]} ]
        then
            tmp=${arr[$j]}
            arr[$j]=${arr[$l]}
            arr[$l]=$tmp
        fi
    done
done
echo "Sorted Data : "
echo ${arr[*]}
```

Comment: The Grumpy Old Men brigade thinks "What is it with expecting an IDE for shell scripting?  Can't people think for themselves?"

Comment: The syntax is a pain in the neck!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that are wrong in your program:

1. Line No. 8 - You are calling your array `arr[]` but later referring it as `a[]` . Change one of the names to match the other.
2. Line No. 10 - There is no `$n` in your program. You mean `$size`. Change this as well.

I think your program should work after this.

Comment: Yes...Wrote this in a copy first, and didn't notice that I changed the names.. And no IDE to warn me, that I did so.. Foolish me... Sorry for this silly thing... Now the program runs fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: You've used $size and $n interchangeably.

Problem 2: You've again used the arr[] and a[] arrays interchangeably.

Comment: Yes...Wrote this in a copy first, and didn't notice that I changed the names.. And no IDE to warn me, that I did so.. Foolish me... Sorry for this silly thing.